# Plot marginal effects on original scale using plot_model()

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot, marginal-effects

Im trying to plot marginal effects from a model (done with lme4) using `plot_model()`

Models (2 versions of same model) look like

Version 1:

```
m1 <- glmer(Y~Xs*Zs+(1|random.factor), family=binomial(), data=dat)
```

Version 2:

```
m2 <- glmer(Y~scale(X)*scale(Z)+(1|random.factor), family=binomial(), data=dat)
```

In both versions the continuous predictor variables X and Z are scaled using the `scale()` function, but in version 1 it is done before creating the model m1 and kept as separate columns (Xs and Zs) in `dataframe=dat`, whereas in version 2 it is specified within the model m2

My question now is
If I plot m1 as it is I get

[Plot without rescaled x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOMs0.png)

I would like to plot marginal effects for X but instead of the scaled values for X on the x-axis I would like to have the original ones
I tried

```
a <- plot_model(m1, type="pred", terms="Xs [myfun]")


b <- plot_model(m2, type="pred", terms="X [myfun]")
```

`myfun` was defined as the reverse function of `scale()`

[Plot a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Eob.png)

[Plot b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pwbr.png)

So, this gives me two different plots. As plot b looks similar to the plot of m1 without rescaled x-axis, I would say plot b is the right one. But I don't understand how the "[myfun]" within the term="..." really works and what it does.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, can't you tell from the range of the data on the x-axis if they're scaled or original?

Comment: Try to fit the model w/o scales variables - it _should_ look like your very first plot (straight line), but with "complete range" at the x-axis. When you scale your variables, the plotted "curve" is correct, so you don't need to apply a function for transforming the values along the x-axis, but you can simply "tweak" the labels at the x-axis (using `+ ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(labels = ...)`).

Comment: You can think of `[myfun]` as if you were calling `predict()` with `newdata`-argument, where you use a range of values from min to max of `Xs` (i.e. the scaled variable), and `myfun` is applied to these values, which is then used in `newdata`... A bit difficult to describe, there's a small paragraph in this vignette: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html#transforming-values-with-functions